# How to use ExtraTreeClassifier to predict multiclass classifications

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm quite new to machine learning techniques, and I'm having trouble following some of the scikit-learn documentation and other stackoverflow posts.. I'm trying to create a simple model from a bunch of medical data that will help me predict which of three classes a patient could fall into.

I load the data via pandas, convert all the objects to integers (Male = 0, Female=1 for example), and run the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import label_binarize
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

# Upload data file with all integers:
data = pd.read_csv('datafile.csv')

y = data["Target"]
features = list(data.columns[:-1]) # Last column being the target data
x = data[features]

ydata = label_binarize(y, classes=[0, 1, 2])
n_classes = ydata.shape[1]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, ydata, test_size=.5)

model2 = ExtraTreesClassifier()
model2.fit(X_train, y_train)

out = model2.predict(X_test)
print np.min(out),np.max(out)
```

The predicted values of `out` range between 0.0 and 1.0, but the classes I am trying to predict are 0,1, and 2. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal behaviour in scikit-learn.

There are two approaches possible:

#### A:You use "label binarize"

- Binarizing transforms `y=[n_samples, ] -> y[n_samples, n_classes]` (1 dimension added; integers in range(0, X) get transformed to binary values)
- Because of this input to fit, `classifier.predict()` will also return results of the form `[n_predict_samples, n_classes]` (with 0 and 1 as the only values) / **That's what you observe!**
- Example output: `[[0 0 0 1], [1 0 0 0], [0 1 0 0]]` = predictions for class: 3, 0, 1

#### B: You skip "label binarize" (multi-class handling automatically done by sklearn)

- Without binarizing (assuming your data is using integer-markers for classes): `y=[n_samples, ]`
- Because of this input to fit, `classifier.predict()` will also return results of the form `[n_predict_samples, ]` (with possibly other values than 0, 1)
- Example output conform to above example: `[3 0 1]`

Both outputs are mentioned in the docs [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.predict):

```
predict(X)

Returns:    
    y : array of shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]
        The predicted classes.
```

**Remark**: the above behaviour should be valid for most/all classifiers! (not only *ExtraTreesClassifier*)